# how to disable HAJNDI on jboss-4.0.3sp1

Tags: jboss, jndi

my test bed is 2 server which all run service based on jboss-4.0.3sp1, they are configured as cluster and has HA-JNDI online between 2 nodes. 
due to some framework change, i need to shutdown the service on one node, how could we shutdown HA-JNDI? 
i can not update cluster-service.xml to remove HA JDNI definition, that will cause application start-up error.

thanks, 
Emre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is from JBoss Clustering documentation:
java.naming.provider.url JNDI setting can now
accept a list of urls separated by a comma. Example:

java.naming.provier.url=server1:1100,server2:1100,server3:1100,server4:1100

When initialising, the JNP client code will try to get in touch with each
server from the list, one after the other, stopping as soon as one server
has been reached.

So set it to server that is up.
I hope it is helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. could you help to figure out which file you mean?

Comment: jndi.properties file. Here is guide to help you: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch3.chapter.html

Comment: Thanks! finally i found my application has internal logic error about  this service, so i can not verify if your solution is good. anyway, many thanks for your help!